# entity framework addorupdate error with DatabaseGenerated field

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Here is my model classes:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Menu : Abstract.BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class SpaceShipEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Menu> Menu { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I use migrations. And there is my configuration class:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SpaceProject.Models.SpaceShipEntities>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(SpaceProject.Models.SpaceShipEntities context)
    {
        context.Menu.AddOrUpdate(
            c => c.Title,
            new Menu() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Главная" }
        );
    }
}
```

When i use package command "Update-Database -Verbose" in empty database new rows has inserted to database. But when i use "Update-Database -Verbose" second time, and Seed method tries to update rows, i have following error:

> When updating records the error occurred. For details, see the inner exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Changing column template "Identity" is not supported. Column: "Id". Table: "CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Menu".

Comment: Seems something to do with the fact you have a Guid that is a key and an int that is auto generated. It's trying to change the identity (key) column from the Guid to the int on the Menu table. Why do you have both these columns - could you get rid of one? Not a solution but it might help work out what's going on!

Comment: I need uniqueidentifier field because another program which works with database needs this type of field as key column. Identity column i use for sorting and numeration.

Answer (score 0):

The Guid will be indexed anyway if you use it as a key. I would use Id as the key and decorate Guid with [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]  then seed it with:

```
protected override void Seed(SpaceProject.Models.SpaceShipEntities context)
    {
        context.Menu.AddOrUpdate(
            c => c.Guid,
            new Menu() { Guid = Guid.Parse("..."), Title = "Главная" }
        );
    }
```